# Hilt + Espresso: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso, dagger-hilt

When using Hilt with Espresso I found that my activity is either not resumed or not destroyed. When I comment out the very first test that launches my activity the second one started to pass. The workaround is to separate each test however this will produce a lot of boiler plate code.

Also I have a custom activity inside the tests that inherits from my main activity.

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@HiltAndroidTest
public class MainActivityTest {
    // ... initilisation & mocks


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        hiltAndroidRule.inject();
        context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        
        // ... other initialisation and setup
    }

    // Helper classes and functions
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    public class ModifiedMainActivity extends MainActivity {
        // ... custom activity implementations
    }

    // Factory
    private SingleActivityFactory<MainActivity> activityFactory = new SingleActivityFactory<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class) {
        @Override
        protected MainActivity create(Intent intent) {
            ModifiedMainActivity mainActivity = new ModifiedMainActivity();
            // other custom activity configuration & setup
            return mainActivity;
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // ... other code to tear down some stubs
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

I can provide some code but other is under NDA.

My rules:

```java
@Rule(order = 0)
public HiltAndroidRule hiltAndroidRule = new HiltAndroidRule(this);
@Rule(order = 1)
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(activityFactory, true, false);
```

Test example:

```java
@Test
public void test_report_system_back_button_pressed_when_closing_main_activity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    final MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(mainActivity::onBackPressed);
    verify(mockedHelper, times(1)).reportEvent(eq(Codes.SYSTEM_BACK_PRESSED), eq("SystemBackPressed"), nullable(Map.class));
}
```

Exception:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:176)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:88)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:37)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:27)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:63)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:280)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:272)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: May I ask what exactly you want to test? I think this is a UI test?

Comment: @Andrew yes, all of the tests inside this class are UI tests. Before adding hilt they were passing with no issues.

Comment: I suggest watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4zG93ogWFY , it shows how to test fragments with dagger hilt